# Only running javascript required for current page, best methods?

Tags: javascript, structure

So I know it's best to have one javascript file for an entire site to limit http requests. So obviously only some javascript is required for some pages. **What is the best way of only running the javascript required for the current page?**

EG.

```
if(page=='home'){
  //run javascript require for the home page
}
```

Maybe this isn't an issue and if targeting elements are not found on the page javascript will just fail gracefully? I would just like to know the best practice for this javascript structure.

Comment: It's probably not the best way to have one(large) file, if only a small part of the file is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encapsulate your logic in functions. Then just call the function(s) you need in each page, either via `"onload"` or an embedded function call in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   yourFunctionForThisPage();
</script>
```

**Edit:** Just to clarify: my answer is assuming the (implied) constraint of a single .js file. As others have pointed out, although you save on HTTP requests, this is not necessarily a good idea: the browser still has to parse *all* the code in the file for each page, whether used or not. To be honest it's pretty unusual to have a global site-wide js resource with everything in it. It's probably a much better idea to logically split out your js into various files, i.e libraries. These libraries could be page-based - i.e specific code for a particular page, or algorithm/task-based that you can include in whatever pages need them.

Comment: Does this really solve the issue? The browser still needs to parse and compile those functions--the ones you wont use--on every page load.

Comment: @Jeremy - well he says he wants all his js in a single file. Is it possible to have all js in one file but _not_ parse and compile the unneeded/unused js?

Comment: @Richard: that's not possible. There are no constructs in Javascript that could be compared to C# compiler directives that could be used in such cases.

Comment: @Robert - that's what I thought, so not sure I understand Jeremy's comment given the constraint of a single js file.

Comment: @Richard: Jeremy just wanted to say that this technique may not be good because whole files will get parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

### Is this feasible?

While it is best to have just a single Javascript file **per page** to lower the number of requests yet it may not be feasible. Especially the way that you'd like to do it.

If you're asking how to join various scripts of various pages into a single script and then running just those parts that are related to a particular page then this is something you shouldn't do. What good is it for you to have one huge file with lots of scripts (also think of maintainability) compared to a few short integrated scripts? If you keep the number of scripts low (ie. below 10) you shouldn't be to worried.

The big downside is also that browser will load the complete script file which means it will take it more time to parse them as well as consume a lot more resources to use it. **I'd strongly suggest against this technique of yours** even though it may look interesting...

### Other possibilities

The thing is that the number of Javascript files per page is low. Depending on the server side technology you're using there are tools that can combine multiple script files into one so every page will just request a single script file which will combine all those scripts that this particular page will use. There is a bit overhead on the server to accomplish this task, but there will be just one script request.

What do you gain?

- every page only has scripts that it needs
- individual script files are smaller hence easier to maintain
- script size per request is small
- browser parsing and resource consumption is kept low

Comment: It may still be one script request, but if the script is constantly changing, then the biggest motivator for a single script file is gone--caching. Then it is probably safer to just have a main common-script and a few extras for your other pages.

Comment: @Jeremy: that's true, but ever website has a rather limited number of pages hence a limited number of scripts will get cached. I don't see this as a problem, since developers are using this technique. But me? I don't bother with less than 10 requests as long as they're small sized.

Comment: I suppose for most sites the ease of use of many scripts is a gain, whereas for bigger sites (like SO) have the traffic to require being a good citizen of the web.

Comment: @Jeremy: Couldn't agree more. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Know what you will need on the page and use a script loader like [labjs](http://labjs.com/).

Also, remember that your specific case might be different from what others have found, so you might want to do some tests, to verify if, for example, having 5 little files, is better (or worse) than 1 big file.
The only way to be sure  is to test different options yourself and come up with a fitting solution.